# connect-mongo latest version return some error in my project

Tags: mongodb

I have updated my connect-mongo npm to the latest version 2.0.1 in node v8 its returning some error, if i comment the below code my projects works pretty well if not returning the below error

here is a bit of code

```
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
    app.use(session({
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        secret: '6256346324',
        store: new MongoStore({
            db: global.db
        })
    }));
```

Error

```
.then(() => this.changeState('connected'))
                     ^

TypeError: this.setCollection(...).setAutoRemoveAsync(...).then is not a function
    at MongoStore.handleNewConnectionAsync
```

modules used in package.json(i have listed only few)

```
connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.35"
```

so how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your error it shows you have **Express 4.16.2** and mongodb 2.2.35.

As per NPM Mongo Blog [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) you can check out the compatibility . As well as for connection integration of **Express 4.x**.

The sample connection code should be as mentioned below for Express 4.x, 5.0 and Connect 3.x:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    store: new MongoStore(options)
}));
```

For further information see [here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) and [here](https://github.com/npmtest/node-npmtest-connect-mongo)